# Expected 1 arguments when using storage in ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, angular-local-storage

I tried using local storage in my ionic service provider app but I got this error.

> [ts] Expected 1 arguments, but got 0. (alias) new Storage(config:
>   StorageConfig): Storage import Storage Create a new Storage instance
>   using the order of drivers and any additional config options to pass
>   to LocalForage.
>
> Possible driver options are: ['sqlite', 'indexeddb', 'websql',
>   'localstorage'] and the default is that exact ordering.

Here is my source code:

```
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';

@Injectable()
export class MyServiceProvider {
  public local : Storage;
  mydata: any;


  constructor(public http: Http) {
    this.local = new Storage()
  }

  postLogin(data){
    let link = "http://myapi.com/api/login.php";
      return this.http.post(link, data)
        .map(data => {
          this.mydata = data;
          console.log("data")
        }, error =>{
          console.log(error)
        })
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I didn't understand well what you want to do with the Storage, but according to Ionic Storage [docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/storage/), you need to inject into your provider/component.

```
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';

export class MyApp {
  constructor(private storage: Storage) { }
}
```

I suggest you to use that provider do get and set the data and you can call these methods wherever you import your provider.

```
public setData(nameData: string, valueData: any){
    this.storage.set(nameData, valueData);
}

public getDataValue(nameData: string){
    return this.storage.get(nameData);
}
```